# What is causing "Network not available" error in rippled RPC call and how to fix it?

Tags: ripple, network, json-rpc, error, daemon

I am running rippled (standard configuration, I only changed `node_db` to `Sqlite`) and communicating with it through JSON RPC. On a few calls I get a response:

```
'error_message': 'Network not available.', 'error_code': 12, 'error': 'noNetwork'
```

The example commands that are doing this are:

```
account_info{"account":"rhPT87PasaG27VqKjEsp5j2AWNSHUWJd9Y"}
wallet_accounts{"regular_seed":"seed"}
```

What is causing this error to appear and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the output of `rippled server_info`? And how long has your server been running?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think I synchronized it fully, and when I need it I run it when testing. The server_info: {"info":{"build_version":"0.17.0-rc2","closed_ledger":{"age":2,"base_fee_xrp":1E-05,"hash":"66AC8BEAB996256DB740781EBFE82E6FF3DBAE464CFA62B0F24171222C0020FD","reserve_base_xrp":200,"reserve_inc_xrp":50,"seq":5},"complete_ledgers":"empty","hostid":"DARKWARE","last_close":{"converge_time_s":2.028,"proposers":0},"load":{"job_types":[{"avg_time":380,"in_progress":2,"job_type":"ledgerData","peak_time":1466,"per_second":2,"waiting":2},

Comment: {"avg_time":5,"job_type":"heartbeat","peak_time":10},{"job_type":"peerCommand","peak_time":13,"per_second":18}],"threads":6},"load_factor":1,"peers":23,"pubkey_node":"n9JjPFq5ibdb9nAs6Y3yFecH2Eq4xD1PdA88LCD2HFoVPHheYvXP","pubkey_validator":"none","published_ledger":"none","server_state":"connected","validation_quorum":1},"status":"success"}

Comment: You have 23 peers. So that looks good. Seeing "complete_ledgers" as "empty" means it hasn't fully accepted any ledgers yet. Make sure your validators and network_quorum are configured the way you want them. (You can use my answer for reference.)

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that your server is not synchronized to the Ripple network and thus doesn't have current information. It's perfectly normal when your server first starts up -- it can take ten or fifteen minutes to sync up, depending on your bandwidth and hardware.

You should make sure you're actually connected to a few servers and have your validators correctly configured. The `server_info` RPC command can help.

The following config entries should help:

```
[ips]
23.23.201.55 51235
184.73.226.101 51235
54.225.112.220 51235
54.225.123.13 51235

[validators]
n9KPnVLn7ewVzHvn218DcEYsnWLzKerTDwhpofhk4Ym1RUq4TeGw
n9LFzWuhKNvXStHAuemfRKFVECLApowncMAM5chSCL9R5ECHGN4V
n94rSdgTyBNGvYg8pZXGuNt59Y5bGAZGxbxyvjDaqD9ceRAgD85P
n9LeQeDcLDMZKjx1TZtrXoLBLo5q1bR1sUQrWG7tEADFU6R27UBp
n9KF6RpvktjNs2MDBkmxpJbup4BKrKeMKDXPhaXkq7cKTwLmWkFr

[validation_quorum]
3
```

You can resolve `r.ripple.com` for a list of server IP addresses recommended by Ripple Labs. Currently the list is `54.225.123.13`, `54.227.239.106`, `107.21.251.218`, `184.73.226.101`, `23.23.201.55`, and `54.225.112.220`.

Comment: It looks like I am lacking the `validators` and `validation_quorum`. Looking at `rippled-example.cfg` it also lacks those entries.

Comment: You can also configure the validators with a `validators.txt` file. The list of validators and the quorum are the current recommended settings if you are not yourself a validator.